# How to convert an image from device to a 3D Tensor in tfjs-react-native?

Tags: react-native, tensorflow.js

There's an example in the documentation https://js.tensorflow.org/api_react_native/0.2.3/#decodeJpeg but it suits only for a situation when you fetch by URL. What to do if I have URI of an image stored on the device?

Comment: On the link you sent, there is `const image = require('path/to/img.jpg');`. The image path can be on the device

Comment: Thanks, it really works but what if I want to load different images. JS does not let me call require a string value that changes in runtime

Comment: Could you please add the relevant code showing what you would like to do to the question?

Answer (score 3):

The solution is given in [this issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/3186#issuecomment-630622541)

I report it here for the sake of clarity:

> Digging into this it looks like fetch is not a good fit for loading these types of files. The api our custom fetch is trying to implement leaves behavior for file:// scheme urls undefined. I probably wouldn't rely on on it for this even where it seems to work. Instead I would use an existing file reading mechanism in react native to get the data. You want to be able to read the file data into one of two formats:

> A UInt8Array
> A base64 encoded string (which will then be converted to a UInt8Array)
> Here is a skeleton of some code using expo-filesystem that you can adapt to your code. We do something similar in our bundleResourceIO model loader (though we use a different library for reading the file).

```js
import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system';

const fileUri = 'NON-HTTP-URI-GOES-HERE';      
const imgB64 = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(fileUri, {
    encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.Base64,
});
const imgBuffer = tf.util.encodeString(imgB64, 'base64').buffer;
const raw = new Uint8Array(imgBuffer)  
const imageTensor = decodeJpeg(raw);
```